# Wagtail new installation : CSS not working

Tags: css, django, wagtail

I tried the official installation guide for installing wagtail locally :

- [first by creating a website](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html)
- [second by integrating wagtail into a new website](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html)

Each time it seemed to work fine functionally but all the CSS was broken (see pic down)

I tried to do "manage.py collectstatic", it told me that 2/3 hundred files have been copied, I emptied the cache of my browser, loaded the page again, no change.

In the console it seems that the files are sent :
[14/Jul/2019 10:16:54] "GET /static/css/welcome_page.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3003

I restarted several times the tutorials from the beginning making sure I do each step exactly as described, nothing changes. When I begin with a new django project, the base django css is working before I add wagtail. I m using Python 3.6.8, Django 2.2.3 and Wagtail 2.5.1. What am I doing wrong ?

[image: Wagtail with broken css]

To answer @Dan Swain comment :

```
Settings.py file :
```

https://pastebin.com/zZqDesnr
[image: Folder structure & wsgi]

Comment: Please post your `wsgi.py`, your settings file that is being accessed by `wsgi.py`, and also your folder structure.

Comment: @DanSwain I included the wsgi.py, settings.py files and the folder structure of the django project where I added wagtail

Comment: Are you developing on runserver or on some other server?

Comment: @DanSwain on local, with "python manage.py runserver"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so simply my django-wagtail server was serving css but with an incorrect mimetype. My browser received the css but because of the wrong mimetype it didn t apply them

I had to add :

```
import mimetypes 
mimetypes.init() 
mimetypes.types_map['.css'] = 'text/css'
```

To my settings files and everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

One standard Wagtail folder structure includes a `settings` *folder* (not just a `settings.py` file).  Inside the `settings` folder you would find `base.py`, `dev.py`, `local.py`, and `production.py`.  You are using, instead, a plain `settings.py` file that is at the same level in the directory structure as your `wsgi.py`.  Inside your `settings.py` you have a `BASE_DIR` declaration that is typically used in the `settings` *folder* setup:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

I think that your problem will be fixed if you change that line to:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: I applied your fix. When I restarted the server, I got an "OperationalError at / no such table: wagtailcore_site". I reverted the changes and I got the "Welcome to your new Wagtail site!" still without CSS

In another folder with another virtual env, I did the whole wagtail installation (http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html)  and got the base.py, dev.py, local.py, and production.py files like you described. The welcome page seems complete but still no CSS, it makes it really hard to use.

Comment: "no such table" might indicate that you need to run `python manage.py migrate` in order to create the Wagtail tables, but I'm not certain since you said you're able, at times, to view the site.

Answer (score 0):

I found missing 3 style files by F12 debugging. Copy the style folder to the target folder. From `wagtail-master\wagtail\admin\static_src\wagtailadmin\scss` to `wagtail-master\wagtail\admin\static\wagtailadmin\css`. That solve my style error.

Answer (score 0):

if CSS is not working in admin panel in wagtail. you should check your nginx setup at first. in nginx there are should be such configurations:

```
location /static/ {
        alias /home/path_to_project/project/staticfiles/;
    }
```

please give attention, there should be alias not root